# Schema design: to-one foreign relation with heterogeneous type (different targets), but same role

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, normalization

I have been working to build a more abstract schema, where there had been several tables modeling remarkably similar relationships, I want to model just the "essence". Due to the environment I am working with (Drupal 7), I can't change the nature of the issue: that a relationship of the same essential type could reference one of two different tables for the object in one role. Let's bring in some example to clarify (this is not my actual problem domain, but a similar problem). Here are the requirements:

First, if you are unfamiliar with Drupal, here's the gist: Users in one table, every other entity in a single second table (gross generalization, but enough).

Let's say we want to model the "works for" relationship, and lets have the given be that "companies" are of type "entity" and "supervisor" is of type "user" (and by "type" I mean that's the table in the database where their tuples reside). Here are the simplified requirements:

1. A user can work for a company
2. A company can work for a company
3. These "works for" relationships should be in the same table.

I have two ideas, and both don't exactly sit well with my current disposition toward schema quality, and this is where I would like some insight.

1. One foreign-key column paired with a 'type' column
2. Two foreign-key columns, always at most one utilized (ick!)

In case you are a visual thinker, here are the two options representing the fact that users 123 and 632, as well as entity 123 all work for entity 435:

```
  Option 1
+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| employment_id | employee_id | employee_type | employer_id |
+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|             1 |         123 |          user |         435 |
+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|             2 |         123 |        entity |         435 |
+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|             3 |         632 |          user |         435 |
+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+

  Option 2
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| employment_id | employee_user_id | employee_entity_id | employer_id |
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|             1 |              123 |             <NULL> |         435 |
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|             2 |           <NULL> |                123 |         435 |
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|             3 |              632 |             <NULL> |         435 |
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

Thoughts on option 1: I like that the employee_id column has *concrete role*, but I despise that it has *ambiguous target*. Option 2 has ambiguous role (*which column is the employee?*), but has concrete target for any given FK, so I can think of it this way:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
|           |         ROLE         |
|           | ambiguous | concrete |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| T         |           |          |
| A  ambig. |           |     1    |
| R         |           |          |
| G  -------+-----------+----------+
| E         |           |          |
| T  concr. |     2     |     ?    |
|           |           |          |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Option two has very pragmatic benefits for my project, but I do not feel comfortable with so many nulls (you might not even call it 1NF!)

So here's the crux of my question for SO: How can option 1 be improved, or else what knowledge gap might I have that leaves me unsettled? While I can't bring to mind a specific *rule* which it violates, the design clearly is not in keeping with the intentions of normalization (requiring two columns to uniquely identify a relationship is not doing me any favors for safeguarding against anomalies).

I do understand that the *ideal* solution would be to redesign the *users* entity to be the *same* as what I have been calling "entity" here, but please consider that beside the point/circumstantial (or at least let's draw the pragmatic line right exactly there for this question).

Again, the essential question: **What, in terms of normalization, is wrong with schema option 1, and how might you model this relationship given the constraint of not refactoring "user" into "entity"?**

**note:** *For this, I am more interested in theoretical purity than a pragmatic solution*

Answer (score 1):

The solutions you present contravene 4th normal form as @podiluska says. If this is recast into the form below, then the solution removes this difficult and is in 5NF (and even 6NF?).

Adopt one of the patterns for sub/super types. This uses the relation definitions set out below, plus the super/subtype constraint. This constraint is that each tuple in the super type relation must correspond exactly to one sub type tuple. In other words, the subtypes must form a disjoint, covering set over the supertype.

I suspect the performance of this in a real situation might require some heavy tuning:

```
    Table: Employment
    +---------------+-------------+
    | employee_id   | employer_id |
    +---------------+-------------+
    |             1 |         435 |
    +---------------+-------------+
    |             2 |         435 |
    +---------------+-------------+
    |             3 |         435 |
    +---------------+-------------+
    Table: Employee (SuperType)
    +---------------+
    | employee_id   |
    +---------------+
    |             1 |
    +---------------+
    |             2 |
    +---------------+
    |             3 |
    +---------------+
    Table: User employee (SubType)
    +---------------+-------------+
    | employee_id   | user_id     |
    +---------------+-------------+
    |             1 |         123 |
    +---------------+-------------+
    |             3 |         632 |
    +---------------+-------------+
    Table: Entity employee (SubType)
    +---------------+-------------+
    | employee_id   |   entity_id |
    +---------------+-------------+
    |             2 |         123 |
    +---------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with option 1 ( and option 2) is that it is a multivalued dependency, and as such, a breach of 4th normal form. However, within the constraints you have given, there's not a lot you can do about that.

If you could replace the `worksfor` table with a view, then you could keep user-company and company-company relations separate.

Of your two choices, Option 2 has the advantage that it may be easier to enforce the referential integrity, depending on your platform.

One potential, if icky, pragmatic solution within you current constraints could be to give companies positive IDs and users negative IDs which eliminates the empty column of option 2 and turns the type column of option 1 into an implication, but I feel dirty even suggesting it.

Similarly, if you don't need to know what type the entity is as long as you can determine it via joining, then using Guids as IDs would eliminate the need for the `type` column